# ASP.NET: Update and delete without using HttpPut and HttpDelete

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I found many open-source projects which do not use `HttpPut` and `HttpDelete` for updating and deleting. Instead, they add the `HttpPost` endpoint before their methods, and the functionalities are implemented successfully as well.

What I learned is that we use `HttpPut` and `HttpDelete` to update and delete. I am confused.

I have added examples of update methods and delete methods below.

UPDATE:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, NewInvoiceVM invoice)
        {
            var allInvoices = await _service.GetAllAsync();

            var invoicesValidate = allInvoices.ToList().FirstOrDefault(n => n.SupplierName == invoice.SupplierName && n.InvoiceNumber == invoice.InvoiceNumber);
            await _service.UpdateInvoiceAsync(invoice);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

DELETE:

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var invoiceDetails = await _service.GetInvoiceByIdAsync(id);
            if (invoiceDetails == null) return View("NotFound");

            await _service.DeleteAsync(id);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

**Question**: Are `HttpPut` and `HttpDelete` required for Update and Delete method? If not, when should we use them?

Comment: What is your question?  And who advised you to use only httpput or httpdelete? must be your school teacher. I never used them for all my life.

Comment: @Serge Just confused why `HttpPut` and `HttpDelete` are not used for Update and Delete methods.

Comment: All of them are  working the same way, maybe Get is a different since it doesn have body. Just don't assign any methods at your APIs at all. Let users decide what to use.

Comment: The reason you **should** use the `HttpDelete` and `HttpPut` annotations is because it's good RESTful symantics.  It's not *necessary*, because in some cases you'll want to include some data in the `body` of the request, which you cannot do with `HttpDelete`, for example.  In general, it's good practice to use the correct annotations, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're implementing an API you have many ways to do it. Using PUT, DELETE, UPDATE etc are all recommended best practices, but there's no need to use them.

You can write an API that listens for a DELETE request to delete something or you can write an API that listens for a POST request with another parameter that tells it if it's a delete, or something else. Both work just fine.

The reason you do it a certain way, is so that when other people come to use your stuff, it will be intuitive for them, if you've used the best practices recommendation. This goes for PUT/POST as it does for all coding best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, web browsers did not have native support for `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, and other verbs. They only support `GET` and `POST`. API's that implemented `PUT` etc. had to do it by sending a `POST` with a hidden field (often named `_method`) to pretend that they were sending something other than a `POST`.

For this reason, many projects just didn't think it was worth implementing.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a example how Microsoft does it. This is the way you should do it in most cases (seems you are using .Net?).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#the-deletetodoitem-method

Maybe the people in the repositories you saw just made mistakes.